# Testing a package that requires the presence of another package (main issue being migrations and factories): with Orchestra/Testbench laravel

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, phpunit, orchestra

Creating a laravel package, which has its own dependencies as well.

The package depends on another package: e.g. lets say I have the two packages .e.g:

```
package: Contractors: 
Above package holds the Contractors details and all that info about the Contractors

pacakge: Accounting: 
This package process the Contractors payments and all other payments of fed into it. 
Kind of acts as the central money processing section.
```

With the above case scenario, When testing say whether hmm, say `testCanWePayAllContractors` We'll need to create a dummy Contractor,

This could be if the `Contractor` model was in the `Accounting` package, we could just include this with:

first include your migrations in the setup() function in the base testCase something like:

`$this->withFactories(__DIR__.'/../database/factories');`
to therefore have: `factory(Contractor::class)->create();`

But this will not see the factories from the other `Contractors` package that is in this case installed as a dependencies in the accounting package.

Note:
[reference to orchestra testbench](https://v6-v7.laravelpackage.com/02-development-environment.html#orchestra-testbench)

Comment: What's your question about this? How is this related to Composer?

Comment: Can you not add the Contractors package in the "require-dev" section of composer.json of Accounting package

Comment: @Donkarnash that is exactly what I have, included it as a dependancy in the Accounting package, I need a constructor in the tests, so upon firing up (factory(Contractor::class), this, returns an error that the facory for the class Contractor not found

Comment: Maybe you could try adding "classmap": [ '/vendor/contractor/database/migration/factories"] in the "autoload-dev" section of composer.json

Comment: @Donkarnash same error, `InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory for [myPackage\Contractors\Models\Contractor]`

Comment: Just to remind did you try to run composer dump-autoload

Comment: @Donkarnash, yeah sure severally